# Bootstrap 4.1: add affix secondary sidebar navigation with scrollspy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

The main navbar (horizontal at the top) is fixed when you scroll down 80px.

Then I have a secondary navbar on the side of the page which uses affix to stay fixed when scrolling down 600px from the top all the way to the footer. Using this plugin https://rawgit.com/bassjobsen/affix/master/assets/js/affix.js?ver=3.3.6 I was able to create a secondary sidenav on my bootstrap 4.1 page.

But I can't get the ScrollSpy to work with the said sidenav

Here is my current setup

```
<body id="ts-theme" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidenav-timeline" data-offset="50">
    <div class="timeline">
        <h2 id="item1">Item 1</h2>
        (... content)
        <h2 id="item2">Item 2</h2>
        (... content)
        <h2 id="item3">Item 3</h2>
        (... content)
    </div>
</body>
```

And now the sidebar which was created according to Bootstrap docs

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 ">
    <div id="sidenav-timeline" class="list-group scrollspy" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="600" data-offset-bottom="800">
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#item1">'Item 1</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#item2">Item 2</a>
          <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#item3">Item 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now for the javascript

```
$('[data-spy="affix"]').on('affixed.bs.affix', function () {
        $(".affix").css("width",$(".affix").parent().css("width").replace('px','') - 1);
})


$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#sidenav-timeline' });
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. use [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/)) so we can run your code and modify?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600368/bootstrap-4-0-affix-scrollspy-and-main-navbar-and-sidenav

Comment: I created a bootply here: http://bootply.com/ffljQZNyon